# MySQL Trigger update

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, triggers

I want to make a trigger that updates the last_modified column of the modified row to the current time. This is what I came up with but when I try and update a row after the trigger is created it won't let me.

```
delimiter $$
create trigger survey_responder_modified
after update on survey_responders
for each row
begin
    update survey_responders
    set last_modified = now();
end
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Sample Trigger code

For Add Current Date in data_create column in Newly Insert Row

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_DatetimeInsert BEFORE INSERT ON tableName FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.date_create = NOW();
END;
```

For Add Current Date in data_modify column in Newly Modified Row

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_DatetimeModify BEFORE UPDATE ON tableName FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.date_modify = NOW();
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to me that it's likely to lead to infinite regress. In other words, in the trigger fired by updating the table, you update the table again, leading to the trigger being fired, ...

Now MySQL *may* be smart enough to prevent that but I wouldn't bet on it, especially when there's an easier way.

This sort of functionality is probably best done as a *before* trigger rather than an after trigger. That way, you set the column before the data ever enters the table.

That would be something along the following lines:

```
create trigger survey_responder_inserting
    before insert on survey_responders
    for each row set new.last_modified = now();
create trigger survey_responder_updating
    before update on survey_responders
    for each row set new.last_modified = now();
```

Note that there are usually *two* triggers involved, one for an insert and one for an update. They both do the same thing in your case since you appear to have only the one "last updated" column but you can use creation and update columns if the need arises.

Comment: I tried changing it to before, but it still won't let me update the table after the triggers creation. I get the error Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'survey_responders' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by the statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: When I tried your code it gave me another error saying Unknown system variable 'last_modified'

Comment: @Dusster, apologies for that, left of the "new" specifier, fixed now.